# How do I make my Raspberry Pi act as a wireless USB controller? Not over the same network but remotely using a 3G/4G & LTE Base HAT

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb, pi-4

I am trying to download data from a USB based device remotely. i.e. Using a WiFi dongle or 3G/4G & LTE Base HAT.

Am I able to install a driver for a WiFi dongle or 3G/4G & LTE Base HAT on an android based Raspberry Pi?

I need the Raspberry Pi to act as a USB controller remotely i.e. not over the same local network but remotely using a 3G/4G & LTE Base HAT. So far I have only been able to get it to work over the same local network.

Comment: USB is VERY sensitive to delays. Those are limited in the USB standard, inside protocol definition (i.e. device must answer within some fixed time, else it is declared as misbehaving). USB cables length is limited partially because of delays. WWANs, on the other hand, often has very large and unpredictable delays (>100 ms, large jitter), which is unsutiable to USB. So it might be completely impossible to run emulated USB hardware protocols tunneled via 3G/4G networks. It is only possible to run upper-layer protocols this way,

Comment: Also, a side note, there is nothing RPi-special in this question, You simply do things common to any computer. SuperUser might be a better place for this topic.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov thank you for your comment :) I have been trying with VirtualHere & flexihub which allows me to access the USB ports over the same local network. But to be honest I am just very confused now.

Answer (score 3):

You can establish remote access using **ssh** with the equipment you like. Then you can mount the USB drive for example at `/mnt/myusbdrive`. From you (home)server you can just use **scp** to download files from the USB drive:

```
rpi ~$ scp pi@remotepi:/mnt/myusbdrive/file .   # dot as last character
```

This will download the `file` into the current directory. It is no problem to use this command in a bash script so you can simply do it automatically.